# How do I programatically track error messages/

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Lookup activity with a Failure output which executes a Stored Procedure activity. The Stored Procedure activity logs the failure. How do I programmatically get the name of the erroring Lookup activity and also the error message as in input parameters to the Stored Procedure activity? Thanks.

Comment: Hi,if you think helps you,could mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the example sdk code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically#net) to get the error messages from the activity which runs in the pipeline.

1.Run the Lookup activity pipeline.

```
CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName).Result.Body;
Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run ID: " + runResponse.RunId);
```

2.Get the error message if it crashed into some issues.

```
List<ActivityRun> activityRuns = client.ActivityRuns.ListByPipelineRun(
resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, runResponse.RunId, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-10), DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)).ToList(); 
if (pipelineRun.Status == "Succeeded")
Console.WriteLine(activityRuns.First().Output);
else
Console.WriteLine(activityRuns.First().Error);
```

3.Then run another sp activity pipeline with the above messages as parameters.

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "errorMessage", activityRuns.First().Error}
};
CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, parameters: parameters).Result.Body;
Console.WriteLine("Pipeline run ID: " + runResponse.RunId);
```